# MKMapView renderInContext - iPhone 4 (Retina) issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having a MKMapView of size 64x64. I am creating an image from map view using 'renderInContext:' method. And assigning the image to UITableViewCell's imageView. In normal iPhone, its showing the image correct. But in iPhone(Retina) its showing the image blurred. I am tesing this in simulator, not in actual device. I have attached the screen shots below.

[image]

The thumbnail in the left side, with rounded corners is the UITableViewCell's imageView. The thumbnail in the right side is MKMapView.

I am using the following code to get the image from map view.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(64, 64));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[mapView layer] renderInContext:context];
thumbnail_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Why this happens in iPhone(Retina)? How to fix this?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219496/rendering-mkmapview-to-uiimage-with-real-resolution/4219721#4219721

Comment: Hai Sir Gudevening, How to create the thumbnail(75*75) image from mkmapview?  Like above image ...if u have any possibility  plz provide the sample code ...thank you .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As already mentioned in a [previous answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219496/rendering-mkmapview-to-uiimage-with-real-resolution/4219721#4219721):

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(64, 64), NO, 0.0);
```

See [QA1703](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html) for more details.  It says:

> Note: Starting from iOS 4,
>   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions
>   allows you to provide with a scale
>   factor. A scale factor of zero sets it
>   to the scale factor of the device's
>   main screen. This enables you to get
>   the sharpest, highest-resolustion
>   snapshot of the display, including a
>   Retina Display.

Comment: This is a note to myself since I keep searching up this question and getting confused. The UIImage returned from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() in this case will be 64x64, not 128x128 as you might think--UIImage (and the underlying CGImage) has an additional scale property. I was putting the image into a GL texture and using the image (point) size, forgetting that I need to multiply that by the scale to get the pixel dimensions. Do try to remember that next time, future me.

Answer (score 1):

could you please provide some sample code (because I'm really interested how you done that in fact it's new for me ^^)
And what I've done in a comparable situation I create an image with double the size and then let it shrink down automatically by `UIImageView` (setting the resize properties to fit all borders)

**EDIT:** but I think it should make the `ScaleToFill` automatically

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(128, 128));    
…
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: How to set the resize property? Actually the image view is UITableViewCell's imageView.